# jQuery: How to turn this URL into a GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest

I'm just messing around with the Factual API but I don't fully understand how to represent a URL as a get request.  The following is the URL I want to turn into a jQuery get:

```
http://api.factual.com/v2/tables/7HOTBC/read?APIKey=SoX1rlj4x8VfRfvqnnehVH5ObpkHJc0kIzloTtxor5gyrHG5c3EySCTTcErCyRYO&filters={"category":{"$bw":"Arts%2C%20Entertainment%20%26%20Nightlife%20%3E%20Bars"},"latitude":{"$blank":false},"longitude":{"$blank":false},"$search":["London"],"$loc":{"$within_dist":[51.5149943,-0.0638818,1000]}}
```

This is the code I have written to do this:

```
    var factualKey = "SoX1rlj4x8VfRfvqnnehVH5ObpkHJc0kIzloTtxor5gyrHG5c3EySCTTcErCyRYO";

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // initialise google maps
        initializeGoogleMaps();

        // make a get request to the factual api
        $.get(
                "http://api.factual.com/v2/tables/7HOTBC/read",
                { APIKey : factualKey,
                  filters : { category : { $bw : "Arts, Entertainment & Nightlife > Bars" },
                              latitude : { $blank : false },
                              longitude : { $blank : false },
                              $search : "[\"London\"]",
                              $loc : { $within_dist : [51.5149943,-0.0638818,1000] }
                  }
                },
                function(responseData){
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                },
                "json"
        );
    });
```

When I look in firebug this is what the address of my request has come out like:

```
http://api.factual.com/v2/tables/7HOTBC/read?APIKey=SoX1rlj4x8VfRfvqnnehVH5ObpkHJc0kIzloTtxor5gyrHG5c3EySCTTcErCyRYO&filters[category][%24bw]=Arts%2C+Entertainment+%26+Nightlife+%3E+Bars&filters[latitude][%24blank]=false&filters[longitude][%24blank]=false&filters[%24search]=[%22London%22]&filters[%24loc][%24within_dist][]=51.5149943&filters[%24loc][%24within_dist][]=-0.0638818&filters[%24loc][%24within_dist][]=1000
```

...which is obviously wrong!

And here's the response from the Factual API:

```
{"version":"2","status":"error","error":"Your filters parameter cannot be parsed. Please see http:\/\/wiki.developer.factual.com\/Server-API for documentation.","error_type":"Api::Error::InvalidArgument"}
```

Can someone tell me what I haven't done properly in my code?  Am I meant to encode the data I'm passing as part of the get request?  Or is it something I've missed?

Comment: Try sending your data through `$.param()`. `$.param({APIKey:factualKey, filt...})`

Comment: ...nevermind, I get the same error you're getting when I do that.

Comment: I think you need to turn your filters : into a JSON string and then urlencode that. Right now it looks as if jQuery is trying to preserve the object using the brackets --> filter[category][$bw]=etc... And what you really want is --> &filters={ url encoded json data no hijacked by jQuery paramterizatoin (sp?) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I got a successful querystring using your object.

```
$.param({ APIKey : factualKey,
          filters : JSON.stringify({ category : { $bw : "Arts, Entertainment & Nightlife > Bars" },
                      latitude : { $blank : false },
                      longitude : { $blank : false },
                      $search : "[\"London\"]",
                      $loc : { $within_dist : [51.5149943,-0.0638818,1000] }
          })
});
```

Same as what you're doing, except that I `JSON.stringify` the filters, and `$.param` the entire thing.

Not sure if the `$.param` is needed. Could be that jQuery does it.

Also not sure if you'll hit same origin policy issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper function for jQuery for the job:

> [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
>
> Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query
>   string. If the value of the data parameter is an object (map), it is
>   converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the
>   URL.

As your JSON data is getting mangled...

Comment: so does $.get also url-encode the string? because it looks like that's what i'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var factualKey = "SoX1rlj4x8VfRfvqnnehVH5ObpkHJc0kIzloTtxor5gyrHG5c3EySCTTcErCyRYO";
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
>     // initialise google maps
>     initializeGoogleMaps();
>
>     // make a get request to the factual api
>     $.getJSON(
>             "http://api.factual.com/v2/tables/7HOTBC/read",
>             { APIKey : factualKey,
>               filters : JSON.stringify({ category : { $bw : "Arts, Entertainment & Nightlife > Bars" },
>                           latitude : { $blank : false },
>                           longitude : { $blank : false },
>                           $search : "[\"London\"]",
>                           $loc : { $within_dist : [51.5149943,-0.0638818,1000] }
>               })
>             },
>             function(data){
>                 console.log(data);
>             }
>     );
> });
> ```